# Multilevel Longitudinal Modelling w/ level 2 trait scores ( lme4 package (lmer) )

Tags: regression, panel-data, multilevel-analysis

In a given (longitudinal) dataset, each Ss has been measured four times (= *wave*) on a depression survey (= *cesd*). We tested the fit of each successive model, using only level-1 predictors (*wave, rses (self-esteem), resp (parental support) & sex*) with a LogLikelihood Ratio Test (LRT).

*I am assuming that we start with level 1 first, and then later add level 2 predictors.*

The sub-final model is:

`model8 <- lmer( cesd ~ 1 + wave + rses*resp + sex + ( 1 + wave | id ) , data = df )`

Literature tells us that the Big Five personality traits influence how depression develops (or doesn't). Thus we want to add the five traits to the model (on level 2). The first (successive) model (model10) has been fitted on the data:

`model10 <- lmer( cesd ~ 1 + wave + rses*resp + sex + ( 1 + wave + open | id ) , data = df )`

The moment we add *cons* (conscientiousness) to our model,

`model11 <- lmer( cesd ~ 1 + wave + rses*resp + sex + ( 1 + wave + open + cons | id  ) , data = df )`

, the error pops up that we have more random effects than we have observations. We understand that this is due to the added random intercepts of the level-2 predictors - but we are not really sure how to continue on this.

*This is where we kinda get lost*

We thought that it would solve this problem if we changed it to 0 + [formula]

`model10b <- lmer( cesd ~ 1 + wave + rses*resp + sex + ( 1 + wave | id ) + ( 0 + open + cons | id ) , data = df )`

It did solve the [ N < *p* ] problem, but we get perfect correlations in our summary(). We aren't really sure if we did the right thing in writing down the lmer() function.

Because, for example, we may assume that a higher score on Neuroticism would imply a stronger increase/decline and/or even a higher average depression score, thus this trait should affect slope as well as intercept (correct me if I am wrong).

So what we want to do, is model it in a way that the Big Five traits have an influence on the level-1 predictors. But looking at how we wrote it down, we will either have a ton of parameters or an incorrect model (lack of intercept).

We are wondering what the appropriate course of action would be, we are stuck due to something with trees and a forest :(

---

Sample of the first 16 observations or first 4 Ss:

`sex     neur     cons     open     agre     extr   id  wave   cesd   rses  resp
1    1 1.750000 3.500000 3.500000 4.666667 3.666667  1    1 2.416667  3.4 2.714286
2    1 1.750000 3.500000 3.500000 4.666667 3.666667  1    2       NA   NA       NA
3    1 1.750000 3.500000 3.500000 4.666667 3.666667  1    3 1.833333  3.5 3.000000
4    1 1.750000 3.500000 3.500000 4.666667 3.666667  1    4       NA   NA       NA
5    0 3.250000 3.750000 3.666667 3.166667 3.000000  2    1 1.750000  2.6 3.000000
6    0 3.250000 3.750000 3.666667 3.166667 3.000000  2    2 2.166667  2.4 3.142857
7    0 3.250000 3.750000 3.666667 3.166667 3.000000  2    3 1.416667  2.9 2.571429
8    0 3.250000 3.750000 3.666667 3.166667 3.000000  2    4 1.416667  2.9 3.857143
9    0 1.833333 2.750000 3.916667 4.166667 4.833333  3    1 1.166667  3.8 4.000000
10   0 1.833333 2.750000 3.916667 4.166667 4.833333  3    2 1.333333  3.9 4.000000
11   0 1.833333 2.750000 3.916667 4.166667 4.833333  3    3       NA   NA       NA
12   0 1.833333 2.750000 3.916667 4.166667 4.833333  3    4       NA   NA       NA
13   1 2.416667 3.666667 3.833333 2.916667 3.500000  4    1 1.750000  3.7 5.000000
14   1 2.416667 3.666667 3.833333 2.916667 3.500000  4    2       NA   NA       NA
15   1 2.416667 3.666667 3.833333 2.916667 3.500000  4    3       NA   NA       NA
16   1 2.416667 3.666667 3.833333 2.916667 3.500000  4    4       NA   NA       NA`